How to turn VersionedTransaction with Address Lookup Tables into VersionedTransaction without Address Lookup Tables
I have a versioned transaction with an address lookup table. However, I need to convert it to one without an address lookup table (that is, the addresses will contribute to the 1232 byte limit per transaction). How would I go about doing this?
Preferred language: Typescript then Python if necessary

I think you can just grab the instructions and create a new transaction with them
const V0MessageWithLUT = .... // update with your transaction

let instructions = TransactionMessage.decompile(V0TxWithLUT).instructions;

const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
    payerKey: me.publicKey,
    recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
    instructions: [...instructions],
}).compileToV0Message();

let tx = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);


Did you mean V0TxWithLUT.message? When I pass that into the decompile function, it doesn't work. Error message below.

Promise {
 Error: Failed to get account keys because address table lookups were not resolved
at MessageV0.getAccountKeys (C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Projects\XX\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\message\v0.ts:105:13)
at Function.decompile (C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Projects\XX\node_modules@solana\web3.js\src\transaction\message.ts:57:33)
at conv (C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Projects\XX\server.ts:230:39)
at C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Projects\XX\server.ts:283:13
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
}

This is the function I tried to use. lang-ts async function conv(V0TxWithLUT: VersionedTransaction, wallet:Wallet){ let instructions = TransactionMessage.decompile(V0TxWithLUT.message).instructions; console.log(instructions) console.log("\n\n\n") const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({ payerKey: wallet.publicKey, recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash, instructions: [...instructions], }).compileToV0Message(); console.log(messageV0) return new VersionedTransaction(messageV0) }

can you check if this answer solves the error https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/13479/1708
